# sql query for like to Order exact match at top in list

Tags: sql, oracle

sql query for like to show exact match first in list:
dataset: "abcd", "a","b","bc","bcd"

```
select * from table where data like "%bc%";
```

it should show in order bc, abcd, bcd.

Comment: Why is `bcd` last?

Comment: it doesn't matter it just give prefer to exact match @juergend

Comment: without order by there is no gurantee of showing in any order

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a query like this one that can return your expected result.

```
select * from table where data='bc'
union all
select * from table where data like '%bc%' and data<>'bc'
```

Comment: `union all` is not guaranteed to return the results in a particular order.

Comment: I did edit my answer, if we add an Order by to end of second select command, it will return exact result as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you said - sort by *match*.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abcd' from dual union all
  3     select 'a'    from dual union all
  4     select 'b'    from dual union all
  5     select 'bc'   from dual union all
  6     select 'bcd'  from dual
  7    )
  8  select col
  9  from test
 10  where col like '%' || '&&par_search_string' ||'%'
 11  order by utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(col, '&&par_search_string') desc;
Enter value for par_search_string: bc

COL
----
bc
bcd
abcd

SQL> undefine par_search_string
SQL> /
Enter value for par_search_string: cd

COL
----
bcd
abcd

SQL>
```

Comment: Massive overkill. Gordon Linoff and Andrei Ogedov show much more efficient ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of many methods:

```
with
  t as (
    select 'abcd' c from dual union all
    select 'a'    from dual union all
    select 'b'    from dual union all
    select 'bc'   from dual union all
    select 'bcd'  from dual
  )
select *
from t
where c like '%bc%'
order by length(c)
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/HJAOO39578).

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select *
from t
where data like '%bc%'
order by (case when data = 'bc' then 1 else 2 end);
```

Or if you don't want to type so much:

```
order by nullif(data, 'bc') desc
```

The descending sort puts `NULL` values first.